# Two div elements conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I am encountering is that when I try to load **dashboard.html** in javascript and then put `<div id="dash" style="..."></div>` below `<div id="toolbar">` the whole **dashboard.html** file is invisible? But if I put `<div id="toolbar">` below `<div id="dash" style="..."></div>` then **dashboard.html**is visible? I want toolbar to be above and not below, how can I make this work?

index.html (This does not work because dash is below toolbar..)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs-1.6.2/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script> 
        $(function(){

        $("#toolbar").load("TopNavigationBar.html");
        $("#dash").load("dashboard.html");
        }); 
    </script> 

</head>
<body>

      <div id="toolbar">
      <div id="dash" style="height:600px;width:1280px; background-image: url('img/dashboard-layout.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #303032;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

index.html (This works because dash is above toolbar..)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs-1.6.2/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script> 
        $(function(){

            $("#toolbar").load("TopNavigationBar.html");
        $("#dash").load("index.html");
        $("#selectTable").load("ListOfTableSensors.html"); 
        }); 
    </script> 

</head>
<body>
      <div id="dash" style="height:600px;width:1280px; background-image: url('img/dashboard-layout.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #303032;"></div>
        <div id="toolbar">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your closed div for `<div id="toolbar"> </???>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your

```
<div id="toolbar">
```

Change it to

```
<div id="toolbar"></div>
```

and it should do what you want.

To test try

```
<div id="toolbar">Hello</div>
  <div id="dash" style="height:600px;width:1280px; background-image: url('img/dashboard-layout.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #303032;"></div>
```

and you will see the `hello` above `dash` div.

Comment: Well this was embarrassing.. How could I not see that! Thank you so much it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to close toolbar div.

Comment: That is correct, small eye mistake I made. The problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

copy this code. You forgot to close you div with id='toolbar' .

```
<div id="toolbar"></div>
  <div id="dash" style="height:600px;width:1280px; background-image: url('img/dashboard-layout.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #303032;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for finding the problem.

Comment: Please add an explanation Sam.  @DlerHasan please accept if this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css::

```
#toolbar {display:block;clear:both;height:auto;}
```